# Sort command on a numeric column is removing the columns

Tags: linux, sort

I am using the following sort command on a numeric column of large tab separated file. When I use the sort command, I notice that the column that the sort is being done on it and the column before that are removed. I haven't used sort command before and I am suspicious I may be doing something wrong. Here is an example:

```
sort --parallel=24 -t$'\t' -k3,3g -n unsorted.tsv > sorted.tsv
```

input file:

```
idx yyy sec
a   0   1583020814
a   0   1583020811
b   1   1583020811
```

Comment: be aware that `-n`  implies a general numeric sort, which you then override by asking to sort on column 3. I wonder whether you have carriage returns embedded in your file, causing it to *appear* to overwrite the first columns with the third.

Comment: @JeffSchaller the type of the file ending is this "UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines".

Comment: do you have a diffrence when you count lines on sorted.tsv and unsorted.tsv  ?

Comment: @EchoMike444 no they have the same number of lines.

Comment: i will  do   a `sort unsorted.tsv > a.sort` and `sort sorted,tsv > b.sort`   and `diff a.sort and b.sort`to check if  i am loosing data

Comment: If there are lines that erroneously miss values and contain just one number in their *first* column then they will appear at the beginning of `sorted.tsv`. If you examine the file with `head`, `less` or some editor then it will appear there is just one column. Does `tail sorted.tsv` reveal more columns?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes it does. But when I count the total columns it shows less columns.